# Copy drop-down list and conditional formatting to new cell with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following to copy a range of free text boxes to another series of cells, which works as I want it to:

```
Public Sub LogEntry()
    'define source range
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("C4:J4")

    'find next free cell in destination sheet
    Dim NextFreeCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
        If IsEmpty(.Range("C8").Value) Then
            Set NextFreeCell = .Range("C8")
        Else
            Set NextFreeCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
                
    'copy & paste
    SourceRange.Copy
    NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    'delete text box
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Goto Reference:="R4C7:R4C9"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents 
End Sub
```

In my original fields, in box J4, I have a drop down list. How do I copy this to the new location and maintain the list functionality? I also want to add conditional formatting to the selections in this box so would like this carried forward also?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy *(rather than `Copy` followed by `PasteSpecial`)* a cell, the data validation will copy with it:

[image]

the code:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim J4 As Range, K5 As Range
    
    Set J4 = Range("J4")
    Set K5 = Range("K5")
    
    J4.Copy K5
End Sub
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: I should have specified; the use 'copy' and 'paste special' is necessary to carry over various functionality in the original free text fields (time, date etc). So, I just need an extra piece of code to bring down the drop list into the pasted area, which as you'll see is in a 'find next free cell' format.